# Jquery AJAX Post not hitting method in code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an ASP.NET website which uses jQuery 1.8.2.  I have a dialog box which lists UserReporting Settings from a DB whether a column is displayed or not.  The User can change this by clicking the change columns buttons which open the dialog box - there are then a list of Available Columns and Current Columns and the User can drag and drop from one side to the other.

The code in the Update button off the dialog button is what is not working - the 'Hello' alert fires but if I set a breakpoint in my ashx Handler it never gets hit?

```
        $("#UserReportSettings").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 600,
            width: 525,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Update Columns": function () {
                    var columns = [];

                    $('#currentColumnsList').each(function () {
                        // this is inner scope, in reference to the .phrase element
                        var column = '';
                        $(this).find('li').each(function () {
                            // cache jquery var
                            var current = $(this);
                            // check if our current li has children (sub elements)
                            // if it does, skip it
                            // ps, you can work with this by seeing if the first child
                            // is a UL with blank inside and odd your custom BLANK text
                            if (current.children().size() > 0) {
                                return true;
                            }
                            // add current text to our current phrase
                            column += (current.text() + ',');
                        });
                        // now that our current phrase is completely build we add it to our outer array
                        columns.push(column);
                    });

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/MyWebsite/Handlers/UpdateUserReportingSettings.ashx',
                        data: { reportingSettings: columns.join() },
                        beforeSend: function (xhr, opts) {
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert("Hello");
                            window.top.location.href = "landing.aspx";
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            alert('error' + xhr.responseText);
                       }
                    });

                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
```

EDIT - Following Archers comment

If I paste *localhost/Handlers/UpdateUserReportingSettings.ashx* into the browser I can hit break point in my Handler.

So changed my URL in ajax call to :

```
url: '/MyWebsite/Handlers/UpdateUserReportingSettings.ashx',
```

and did a shift refresh to reload the js for page and hit the breakpoint.

Comment: you redirecting to landing.aspx .then how it will hit ashx page ?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you've got a typo in the url.  Can you hit the ashx file in the address bar of a browser?

Comment: @SivaRajini He's doing the redirect after an alert, but that's not relevant.  He says he put a breakpoint in the ashx file and it was never hit.

Comment: @Archer - ill check pasting the url directly in the browser though I dont think there is a typo in it.

Comment: @Archer - fixed and working following your comments - Cheers :)

Comment: Rather than posting the solution in your question, post it as an answer (and remove the solution from your question). This makes it clearer how to solve this for anyone else that happens along your question.

Comment: @mason - was going to to that but you cant answer your own question for 2 days so have put it as an EDIT in question until then